# How to fix pointer on screen to desired position?

Tags: winforms, mailmerge

I am working on mail merge using Winform as a tool. I've provided 2 templates, one for business letters and another for memos. For letters, the user usually types the body of the letter while other information is picked from a data file that is created by user by clicking on "Select Recipient" option.

I want to restrict my user to only type the body, and the pointer **must** be positioned following the second line of salutation. The pointer can't move backward from that position but, of course, can move forward. How do I do this?

I am sorry for being unclear, if I am.

Comment: Please provide more detail how are you using these templates in your winform app ? Also can you provide some code ? http://whathaveyourtried.com

Answer (score 0):

If your text is in a `TextBox` or a `RichTextBox` you can select the control and place the cursor with

```
// Set the cursor into the text box
bodyTextBox.Focus();

// Place the cursor at the desired position in the text
bodyTextBox.Select(start, 0);
```

You will have to figure out where the third line starts

```
const int indent = 30; // Desired indentation

// Place focus in this control
bodyTextBox.Focus();

// The following work only if we have at least 3 lines of text
if (bodyTextBox.Lines.Length >= 3) {

    int start = bodyTextBox.Lines[0].Length + // Length of first line
                bodyTextBox.Lines[1].Length + // Length of second line
                4 +   // 2 x 2 characters for two CR-LFs
                Math.Min(indent, bodyTextBox.Lines[2].Length);
    bodyTextBox.Select(start, 0);
}
```

I assume that the text looks like this

```
First line of text.<CR><LF>
Second line of text.<CR><LF>
<30 spaces for indent>
                      ^ desired position
```

In order to set the cursor at the right place, we need to count the total number of characters from the beginning of the text. Since you want to position the cursor on the third line, this is the length of two first lines plus the two CR-LFs (the line break characters) at their end plus the 30 characters at the beginning of the third line. If the third line is less than 30 characters long, we cannot place the cursor there, therefore we place it at far as possible to the right, i.e. on the last character of this line with `Math.Min(indent, bodyTextBox.Lines[2].Length);`

Finally we place the cursor there with `Select`. Since we do not want to select text, we define the length of the selection as zero.

Comment: No, no my text is in a RichTextBox while textbixes are reserved for data (like recipient and sender's address, sender's name and other information parameters will be placed in text box) that is going to be retrieved from data file as mentioned above. I want to change position of cursor in RTB document (text boxes are contained in RTB document)

Comment: You did not specify that; however, this is not a problem, since both `TextBox` and `RichTextBox` inherit their `Lines` property and `Select` method from `TextBoxBase` and the `Focus` method from `Control`. This means that the exact same solution should work for a `RichTextBox` as well.

Comment: I added code comments and an explanation. (Note: This is a C# code. I do not see any language tag nor any mention of a language in your question.)

Comment: I am also working on C# so its not a problem, suppose that RTB is blank i want user to start typing from 10th line leaving 10 lines blank (no text here). when form displayed to the user then cursor MUST be at 10th line (user not allowed to enter text in that region i-e starting 10 lines).

Comment: If the user has to start typing from the 10th line you will have to enter 9 times "\r\n" (CR-LF) and place the cursor with `Select(18,0)`; however, you can not prevent him from writing in the wrong lines.